How do I lock an iOS app from accidental touch in pocket?
I have an iPhone 15 Pro Max on latest public release iOS.I deliver Doordash for extra cash.  The driver app is called “Dasher”.  I constantly need to pocket the phone so I can carry orders, open doors, etc. I am constantly pulling the phone back out of my pocket to discover the Dasher app had somehow woken the phone, brought itself to the front, and initiated some sort of negative action.  Usually this is either kicking me out of the system (without ability to get back for HOURS or DAYS), or accepting orders so poor that I’m paying doordash to allow me to deliver them.
I’m trying to think of a way to allow the app to run normally when pocketed (alerts, offers, customer texts, whatever), but DISALLOW touch input until I allow it.
Ideally, perhaps that single app can not accept touch input until Face ID is successful.

Get in the habit of locking the screen with the power button before you put the iPhone in your pocket and set up Face Recognition.

I do.  This still keeps happening.

It may add a few seconds to the process, but how about quitting the Dasher app?

This is usually due to no passcode, watch unlock or some settings relating to security and widgets. Feel free to comment on my answer if you have requirements you didn’t list

re: quitting Dasher app….   i’m not actually sure if it would still work if it was closed. I hadn’t considered the idea because testing it can damage my driver rating within seconds

@bmike. 6-digit code always enabled.  No apple watch.  Closing a few widvets now…

Ideally you'd want to use something like Guided Access on iOS.
Go to:

Settings
Accessibility
Guided Access
Activate it

Now open the app you want to lock and limit control to. Dasher in your case.

Triple click on the Power Button of the iPhone.
Select the areas of the app you want to disable to touch.
You're done.

Here is also a video tutorial for reference.

I saw this and ruled it out for some reason but I can’t remember why I’ll look at it again after work.

I remember the issue now. I have to be able to run multiple apps at the same time. If I’m running dasher, I’m probably also running Uber driver at the same time, plus a chat app for driver support, plus apps for doing my own things in between deliveries, text messaging from customers, etc. etc.

The most simple solution is to lock your screen with the side button and verify you have good settings listed below.
One press and you will need to use Face ID or enter your passcode to use any apps including your dashing one.

If you don’t have a passcode, that might help greatly.
Turn off unlock with Apple Watch
Require a passcode immediately
For FaceID, experiment with the “require attention” setting. Use care to not look directly at your phone when you lock it.
Turn off everything in FaceID under “allow access when locked” ( only enable them as needed and test before your work shift gets started.)

Once you’re getting a solid lock every time in the pocket , you can experiment with adding or removing items from the Lock Screen.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/control-access-information-lock-screen-iph9a2a69136/ios


-already have passcode, -No Apple Watch and can’t find this setting, -Already require a passcode immediately, -Require attention or reset On, -Turn off four or five items under allow access when locked.  Starting from here tonight, will see what happens
